# IIS 5.1, HttpHandler based on path, NOT Working. Is it possible to fix with IIRF?

Tags: c#, httphandler, iis-5, url-rewriting, iirf

I have a reverse proxy written in C#/ASP.NET.  After adding a Wildcard Mapping in IIS6 it works just fine.  My problem is that I have to make this application compatible with Windows XP and IIS 5.1.  At first attempt adding a wildcard file type mapped to aspnet_isapi.dll didn't work.  I also tried using a file extention to no avail.

My next path is to explore using Ionic's Isapi Rewrite Filter (IIRF) to reroute requests to my Asp.Net application.  Has anyone used it for this purpose?  Its seems to me like I'd still need to change how my reverse proxy works.

Right now, through a process I generate a connection, so the user sees:

```
http://example.com/remotesite/34x904/home.htm
```

and I have the HttpHandler mapped to the remotesite/ virtual path

```
<add verb="*" path="/remotesite/*" validate="false" type="Proxy.Core.HttpHandler,Proxy.Core"/>
```

and the backend HttpWebRequest will ultimately use a URI like so:

```
http://10.1.1.21/home.htm
```

In IIS 5 I've trine mapping by file extention, but I still get Paged Cannot Be Displayed.

```
<add verb="*" path="test.proxy" validate="false" 
type="Proxy.Core.HttpHandler,Proxy.Core"/>
 <add verb="*" path="/test.proxy/*" validate="false" 
type="Proxy.Core.HttpHandler,Proxy.Core"/>
```